# Adding Apache VirtualHost, DocumentRoot of localhost changes to the VirtualHost's DocumentRoot

Tags: apache, localhost, virtualhost, document-root, hosts-file

Everything is working perfectly in my Windows 7.

The problem is when I add a **domain1.com** as VirtualHost, localhost's DocumentRoot changes to VirtualHost's DocumentRoot.

Eg:
When I visit http://localhost, DocumentRoot which I specified for domain1.com is opened and not the one specified in httpd.conf.

My httpd-vhosts.conf file is:

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80
NameVirtualHost domain1.com:80
<VirtualHost domain1.com:80>
<Directory "e:/program files/apache/htdocs/domain1.com">
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    allow from All
</Directory>
ServerName domain1.com
ServerAlias domain1.com
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "e:/program files/apache/htdocs/domain1.com/cgi-bin/"
DocumentRoot "e:/program files/apache/htdocs/domain1.com"
ErrorLog "E:/Program Files/apache/logs/domain1.com.err"
CustomLog "E:/Program Files/apache/logs/domain1.com.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

My Hosts file :

```
127.0.0.1   domain1.com
```

My httpd.conf file :

```
DocumentRoot "e:/program files/apache/htdocs"
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
<Directory "e:/program files/apache/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I know one solution is to add VirtualHost with ServerName as 127.0.0.1 or localhost but I am avoiding that.

Can I make localhost's DocumentRoot specified in httpd.conf a default one ?

Please let me know if you need additional information.

Thanks,
Jigar.

Answer (score 9):

as stated in https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html

"If you are adding virtual hosts to an existing web server, you must also create a `<VirtualHost>` block for the existing host. The `ServerName` and `DocumentRoot` included in this virtual host should be the same as the global `ServerName` and `DocumentRoot`. List this virtual host first in the configuration file so that it will act as the default host."

Comment: "The `DocumentRoot` included in this virtual host should be the same as the global `DocumentRoot`". This is NOT TRUE. It all depends on your configuration. If you set `Options Indexes FollowSymlinks` for instance, you can set any directory inside the global `DocumentRoot` as the vhost's `DocumentRoot`.